# Game Development lock canvas error

Tags: java, android, game-engine

i keep getting error draw to canvas 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01jIl.jpg)

The error keep happening when I tried to draw to the canvas the player after the user move the joystick
it always writes me "cant lock canvas ,canvas already locked"

i'm kind of beginner in game development and sorry if the question is a little unclear if you need more details just say and I will send you more info

Main class - the main activity

```
package app.shahardagan.Raven;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Main extends Activity {
RelativeLayout layout_joystick;
ImageView image_joystick, image_border;
GameEngine gameEngine;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get a Display object to access screen details
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    // Load the resolution into a Point object
    Point size = new Point();
    size.set(display.getWidth(),display.getHeight());
    layout_joystick = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_joystick);
    gameEngine = new GameEngine(this,size.x,size.y);
    setContentView(gameEngine);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    gameEngine.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    gameEngine.pause();
}
}
```

GameEngine class - responsible to draw the player and update the game

```
package app.shahardagan.Raven;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class GameEngine extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
JoyStickClass js;
// This is our thread
private Thread gameThread = null;

// This is new. We need a SurfaceHolder
// When we use Paint and Canvas in a thread
// We will see it in action in the draw method soon.
private SurfaceHolder ourHolder;

// A boolean which we will set and unset
// when the game is running- or not.
private volatile boolean playing;

// Game is paused at the start
private boolean paused = true;

// A Canvas and a Paint object
private Canvas canvas;
private Paint paint;

// How wide and high is the screen?
private int screenX;
private int screenY;

// This variable tracks the game frame rate
private long fps;

// This is used to help calculate the fps
private long timeThisFrame;
private Context context;

private Player player;

private Drawable playerImage;


public GameEngine(Context context, int x, int y) {
    // This calls the default constructor to setup the rest of the object
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    // Initialize ourHolder and paint objects
    ourHolder = getHolder();
    paint = new Paint();

    // Initialize screenX and screenY because x and y are local
    screenX = x;
    screenY = y;
    prepareLevel();
}
private void prepareLevel(){
    player = new Player(context,screenX,screenY);
}


public void PlayerControls(Context context,RelativeLayout layout_joystick, ImageView image_joystick, ImageView image_border){
    js = new JoyStickClass(context, layout_joystick, R.drawable.image_button);
    js.setStickSize(150, 150);
    js.setLayoutSize(500, 500);
    js.setLayoutAlpha(150);
    js.setStickAlpha(100);
    js.setOffset(90);
    js.setMinimumDistance(50);
    layout_joystick.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            js.drawStick(arg1);
            if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                int direction = js.get8Direction();
                if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UP) {

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UPRIGHT) {
                    player.setMovementState(Player.UP);
                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_RIGHT) {

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWNRIGHT) {

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWN) {

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWNLEFT) {

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_LEFT) {

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UPLEFT) {

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_NONE) {

                }
            } else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

// Runs when the OS calls onPause on BreakoutActivity method
public void pause() {
    playing = false;
    try {
        gameThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", "joining thread");
    }
}

// Runs when the OS calls onResume on BreakoutActivity method
public void resume() {
    playing = true;
    gameThread = new Thread(this);
    gameThread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (playing) {

        // Capture the current time in milliseconds in startFrameTime
        long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Update the frame
        // Update the frame
        if(!paused){
            update();
        }

        // Draw the frame
        draw();

        // Calculate the fps this frame
        // We can then use the result to
        // time animations and more.
        timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
        if (timeThisFrame >= 1) {
            fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
        }

    }
}

private void draw() {
    // Make sure our drawing surface is valid or game will crash
    if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        // Lock the canvas ready to draw
        canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
        // Draw the background color
        canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 26, 128, 182));
        // Draw everything to the screen
        // Choose the brush color for drawing
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        canvas.drawBitmap(player.getBitmap(),player.getX(),screenY - player.getHeight(),paint);

    }
}

private void update() {
    player.update(fps);

}
}
```

Player class - the player class methods

```
 package app.shahardagan.Raven;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.RectF;

public class Player {

// RectF is an object that holds four coordinates - just what we need
private RectF rect;
private Bitmap bitmap;
// How long will our paddle will be
private float length;
private float height;
// X is the far left of the rectangle which forms our paddle
private float x;
private float y;

// Which ways can the player move
final int STOPPED = 0;
public static final int UP = 1;
public static final int UPRIGHT = 2;
public static final int RIGHT = 3;
public static final int DOWNRIGHT = 4;
public static final int DOWN = 5;
public static final int DOWNLEFT = 6;
public static final int LEFT = 7;
public static final int UPLEFT = 8;
// Is the paddle moving and in which direction
private int playerMoving = STOPPED;
private int playerSpeed;

public Player(Context context,int screenX, int screenY){
    rect = new RectF();
    length =screenX/10;
    height = screenX/10;
    x = screenX;
    y= 0;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.eagle_fly);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,(int)length,(int)height,false);
    playerSpeed = 350;
}

public RectF getRect(){
    return rect;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(){
    return bitmap;
}
public float getX(){ return x; }
public float getHeight(){return height;}
private float getLength(){return length;}
public void setMovementState(int state){
    playerMoving = state;
}

void update(long fps){
    if(playerMoving == LEFT){
        x = x - playerSpeed / fps;
    }

    if(playerMoving == RIGHT){
        x = x + playerSpeed / fps;
    }
    rect.top = y;
    rect.bottom = y+ height;
    rect.left = x;
    rect.right = x + length;

}

}
```

Joy stick class

```
 package app.shahardagan.Raven;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

public class JoyStickClass {
  public static final int STICK_NONE = 0;
  public static final int STICK_UP = 1;
  public static final int STICK_UPRIGHT = 2;
  public static final int STICK_RIGHT = 3;
  public static final int STICK_DOWNRIGHT = 4;
  public static final int STICK_DOWN = 5;
  public static final int STICK_DOWNLEFT = 6;
  public static final int STICK_LEFT = 7;
  public static final int STICK_UPLEFT = 8; 

  private int STICK_ALPHA = 200;
  private int LAYOUT_ALPHA = 200;
  private int OFFSET = 0;

  private Context mContext;
  private ViewGroup mLayout;
  private LayoutParams params;
  private int stick_width, stick_height;

  private int position_x = 0, position_y = 0, min_distance = 0;
  private float distance = 0, angle = 0;

  private DrawCanvas draw;
  private Paint paint;
  private Bitmap stick;

  private boolean touch_state = false;

 public JoyStickClass (Context context, ViewGroup layout, int stick_res_id) {
    mContext = context;

    stick = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
            stick_res_id);

    stick_width = stick.getWidth();
    stick_height = stick.getHeight();

    draw = new DrawCanvas(mContext);
    paint = new Paint();
    mLayout = layout;
    params = mLayout.getLayoutParams();
}

public void drawStick(MotionEvent arg1) {
    position_x = (int) (arg1.getX() - (params.width / 2));
    position_y = (int) (arg1.getY() - (params.height / 2));
    distance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(position_x, 2) + Math.pow(position_y, 2));
    angle = (float) cal_angle(position_x, position_y);


    if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if(distance <= (params.width / 2) - OFFSET) {
            draw.position(arg1.getX(), arg1.getY());
            draw();
            touch_state = true;
        }
    } else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && touch_state) {
        if(distance <= (params.width / 2) - OFFSET) {
            draw.position(arg1.getX(), arg1.getY());
            draw();
        } else if(distance > (params.width / 2) - OFFSET){
            float x = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(cal_angle(position_x, position_y))) * ((params.width / 2) - OFFSET));
            float y = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(cal_angle(position_x, position_y))) * ((params.height / 2) - OFFSET));
            x += (params.width / 2);
            y += (params.height / 2);
            draw.position(x, y);
            draw();
        } else {
            mLayout.removeView(draw);
        }
    } else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        mLayout.removeView(draw);
        touch_state = false;
    }
}

public int[] getPosition() {
    if(distance > min_distance && touch_state) {
        return new int[] { position_x, position_y };
    }
    return new int[] { 0, 0 };
}

public int getX() {
    if(distance > min_distance && touch_state) {
        return position_x;
    }
    return 0;
}

public int getY() {
    if(distance > min_distance && touch_state) {
        return position_y;
    }
    return 0;
}

public float getAngle() {
    if(distance > min_distance && touch_state) {
        return angle;
    }
    return 0;
}

public float getDistance() {
    if(distance > min_distance && touch_state) {
        return distance;
    }
    return 0;
}

public void setMinimumDistance(int minDistance) {
    min_distance = minDistance;
}

public int getMinimumDistance() {
    return min_distance;
}

public int get8Direction() {
    if(distance > min_distance && touch_state) {
        if(angle >= 247.5 && angle < 292.5 ) {
            return STICK_UP;
        } else if(angle >= 292.5 && angle < 337.5 ) {
            return STICK_UPRIGHT;
        } else if(angle >= 337.5 || angle < 22.5 ) {
            return STICK_RIGHT;
        } else if(angle >= 22.5 && angle < 67.5 ) {
            return STICK_DOWNRIGHT;
        } else if(angle >= 67.5 && angle < 112.5 ) {
            return STICK_DOWN;
        } else if(angle >= 112.5 && angle < 157.5 ) {
            return STICK_DOWNLEFT;
        } else if(angle >= 157.5 && angle < 202.5 ) {
            return STICK_LEFT;
        } else if(angle >= 202.5 && angle < 247.5 ) {
            return STICK_UPLEFT;
        }
    } else if(distance <= min_distance && touch_state) {
        return STICK_NONE;
    }
    return 0;
}

public int get4Direction() {
    if(distance > min_distance && touch_state) {
        if(angle >= 225 && angle < 315 ) {
            return STICK_UP;
        } else if(angle >= 315 || angle < 45 ) {
            return STICK_RIGHT;
        } else if(angle >= 45 && angle < 135 ) {
            return STICK_DOWN;
        } else if(angle >= 135 && angle < 225 ) {
            return STICK_LEFT;
        }
    } else if(distance <= min_distance && touch_state) {
        return STICK_NONE;
    }
    return 0;
}

public void setOffset(int offset) {
    OFFSET = offset;
}

public int getOffset() {
    return OFFSET;
}

public void setStickAlpha(int alpha) {
    STICK_ALPHA = alpha;
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
}

public int getStickAlpha() {
    return STICK_ALPHA;
}

public void setLayoutAlpha(int alpha) {
    LAYOUT_ALPHA = alpha;
    mLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(alpha);
}

public int getLayoutAlpha() {
    return LAYOUT_ALPHA;
}

public void setStickSize(int width, int height) {
    stick = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(stick, width, height, false);
    stick_width = stick.getWidth();
    stick_height = stick.getHeight();
}

public void setStickWidth(int width) {
    stick = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(stick, width, stick_height, false);
    stick_width = stick.getWidth();
}

public void setStickHeight(int height) {
    stick = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(stick, stick_width, height, false);
    stick_height = stick.getHeight();
}

public int getStickWidth() {
    return stick_width;
}

public int getStickHeight() {
    return stick_height;
}

public void setLayoutSize(int width, int height) {
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
}

public int getLayoutWidth() {
    return params.width;
}

public int getLayoutHeight() {
    return params.height;
}

private double cal_angle(float x, float y) {
    if(x >= 0 && y >= 0)
        return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(y / x));
    else if(x < 0 && y >= 0)
        return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(y / x)) + 180;
    else if(x < 0 && y < 0)
        return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(y / x)) + 180;
    else if(x >= 0 && y < 0) 
        return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(y / x)) + 360;
    return 0;
}

private void draw() {
    try {
        mLayout.removeView(draw);
    } catch (Exception e) { }
    mLayout.addView(draw);
}

private class DrawCanvas extends View{
    float x, y;

    private DrawCanvas(Context mContext) {
         super(mContext);
     }

     public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         canvas.drawBitmap(stick, x, y, paint);
     }

     private void position(float pos_x, float pos_y) {
        x = pos_x - (stick_width / 2);
        y = pos_y - (stick_height / 2);
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your draw() method, you're locking the Canvas, but not unlocking the Canvas after you finish drawing.  So, when you re-enter your draw method, the Canvas is still locked from the previous call.

You likely need to add `unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas canvas)` after you finish drawing.  See the full docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html).

Comment: I already tried it i write this line before the lockCanvas and then it gave me an error too

Comment: Have you tried unlocking it after your bitmap draw call?  Also, can you post your stack trace?

Comment: In the Joystick class I don't use SurfaceHolder so I don't know how to call the method unlockCanvasAndPost.